# How to display ArrayList content as <td> from servlet?

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, servlets

I have large amounts of data in an ArrayList that holds about 2,600 classes from my College. I am trying to build them a JSP page that will display this information. I am having trouble figuring out how to approach displaying this data in a table.

To test out in the beginning, I did this just to verify I could access the data.

HTML:

```
 <html>
  <head>
  <body>
   <button id="btnData">Get all classes.</button>
   <div id="dataDisp></div>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#btnData).click(function(){
       $.get('daoServlet', function(responseText){ 
         $("#dataDisp").text(responseText);
       });
     });
   });
  </body>
 <html>
```

Servlet:

```
 @WebServlet("/daoServlet/*")
 public class ClassDAO extends HttpServlet
 {
   //Code getting my ArrayList<ClassInfo> set up, etc.

   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
   {
      String text = fallClassListings.toString();

      response.setContentType("text/html");
      response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
      response.getWriter().write(text);
   }
 }
```

This will display every single class. So, what direction could I take to format this data into a table in my index.jsp page? I tried doing something like

```
 text = "<h1>This is an h1 tag</h1>";
```

Just to see if I could return some HTML, but that just prints out the whole string literal, not an h1 tag.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: using .text() will only set it as a string.. use `$("#dataDisp").html(responseText);`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, I am very new to jsp so I am still looking over documentation to see how it all comes together. I just hope by setting up a table in my servlet I am not gutting MVC paradigmn :-/

Comment: If you really want just convert your list into a JSON string then you can build it in your JS inside your success function().  It's really easy using [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem that I see with your implementation in jquery is having ".text()". Instead, replace it with ".html()" of the "div" as shown below.

```
$("#dataDisp").html(responseText);
```

Also, you could have a for loop on the list and build the table with "tr"s and "td"s in the Index.jsp file and return the same to jquery.

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: This is great! Thanks @Praveen , I think you have helped me before too by the way :).

Answer (score 0):

If you were to have used the jquery html method instead of the text method you would have seen the h1 appear properly:

```
$("#dataDisp").html(responseText);
```

The best way to do something like this would be to generate a json serialized string on the server, and then you can iterate over the objects in javascript.  Further, you could use a javascript templating engine like mustache to build your table, see https://github.com/janl/mustache.js